# can we consider RDS MYSQL/POSTGRES read replica's as source endpoint for AWS DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

can we consider RDS MYSQL/POSTGRES read replica's as source endpoint for AWS DMS ?

I hava a requirement werein i have to use replica's of RDS MYSQL and RDS POSTGRES as source endpoint in AWS DMS and REDSHIFT cluster as target endpointfor AWS DMS(we have to use FULL load with CDC).

please suggest if it's possible to use replica's of RDS MYSQL and RDS POSTGRES.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on their dedicated DBA sister-site of SO! SO focuses on software development related questions. Please also read what a tag means as multiple products / services may have the same abbreviation.

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you want to do it from the Read Replica? Are you worried about a performance impact on the Primary database?

Comment: Hi John, yes performance impact is the main factor for using the read replica.

Answer (score 0):

On [Using a MySQL-compatible database as a source for AWS DMS - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html), there is a reference to read replicas:

> If you are using an **Amazon RDS MySQL or Amazon RDS MariaDB read replica as a source**, enable backups on the read replica, and ensure the log_slave_updates parameter is set to TRUE.

Therefore, it *seems* to be possible with MySQL on Amazon RDS.

However, [Using a PostgreSQL database as an AWS DMS source - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html) says:

> You can't use RDS PostgreSQL read replicas for CDC (ongoing replication).

However, it seems possible for the initial (full) load.

Comment: Thanks for answering John. appreciated.